# How can an ISV try out Salesforce Anywhere (derived from Quip)?

Tags: quip, salesforce-anywhere

I'm having trouble finding out how I an turn this on to understand it better and consider how we might leverage it in our products.

Anyone know how can I get a license or a trial?

(Is it this https://quip.com/about/salesforce-crm-integration?)

Comment: If you want to try out the Salesforce Anywhere integration, you would need to reach out to your Salesforce Account Executive who can then further assist with the request.

Comment: Thanks @Swetha; will be doing that today.

Comment: Just checking if you got the needed inputs from Account Exec on this

Comment: Hi @Swetha thanks for the follow up. So far our Account Exec has not got back to us on this; relevant information about the company I work for is in "Partner Community Case Number: #30287159".