# What does "bidirectionally" mean for Salesforce Anywhere Components?

Tags: trailhead, quip, salesforce-anywhere

This [Add Salesforce Anywhere Components to Your Salesforce Pages](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/implementing-quip-in-salesforce/add-quip-components-to-your-salesforce-pages?trail_id=quip-for-customer-360) Trailhead uses the term:

> **bidirectionally** sync Salesforce data into Salesforce Anywhere

but as far as I can tell the mechanism is:

- SObject data to Quip document via mail merge fields
- Quip document to Salesforce via the entire document being presented (rather than edits to the Quip document mapping back to SObject fields)

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update Salesforce data within the Quip documents with [Salesforce Live Apps](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.anywhere_live_apps.htm&type=5). You'll notice the next quote in the trailhead mentions what specifically in regards to bidirectional:

> Use Salesforce Live Apps. Use these (**Salesforce Record Live App and Salesforce List View Live App**) to show and update Salesforce data with a bidirectional sync from Salesforce Anywhere documents.

There's the following as examples:

1. [Salesforce List Views in Quip](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.quip_list_live_app_overview.htm&type=5)

> See your Salesforce list views and related lists in Quip. You can do bulk updates, sync your changes to Salesforce, and add list view filters. You can even add notes and next steps that you can share with your team.

2. [Salesforce Record Live App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.quip_record_live_app_overview.htm&type=5)

> See your Salesforce records and customize your record views in Quip. You can do bulk updates and sync your changes to Salesforce. You can even add notes and next steps that you can share with your team.

Adding these to the quip document is as easy as @mentioning and selecting `Salesforce Record` and `Salesforce List`. From there, you can select applicable object, list view, record, etc.

[image]

You can see the `Salesforce List` is just like editing a list view in Salesforce with the option to `Save to Salesforce`. When it's saved, it says `Synced to Salesforce`. Lets you customize which columns to display as well.

[image]

---

In terms of templates and what you mentioned (namely mail merge fields and the quip document in Salesforce), there's a [Salesforce Template Data Mention](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.anywhere_add_template_data_mention.htm&type=5) that adds the bidirectional sync that is lacking with just using [mail merge fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.quip_mail_merge.htm&type=5).

This allows you to create the quip document on a given record from a template, have the fields dynamically display based on your data mentions, and allows users to edit that given data from Quip itself to sync into Salesforce.

Comment: So Kris, I missed the "sync your changes to Salesforce" point. Any idea what that exactly means?

Comment: I can't say I've used it, but it seems like it's just the app within the Quip document that allows updates to Salesforce data. It's presenting a Salesforce list view and Salesforce record within the quip document with the same functionality as if you were in the org. Any updates you make to that particular component (within the Quip document) will actually update the record in Salesforce.

Comment: Thanks Kris that does make some sense. Have yet to get a license to try it out - [How can an ISV try out Salesforce Anywhere (derived from Quip)?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347678/how-can-an-isv-try-out-salesforce-anywhere-derived-from-quip) - so only able to read stuff at the moment.

Comment: I added some screenshots of me using it to showcase it a little bit more (I'm using dark mode which is why it's dark). I'm not an expert with quip, but gives you an idea of how to sync your changes back to Salesforce and the look of it.

Comment: Thanks Kris - helpful. If it correct that both the list and individual record views are editable? Presumably the merge fields are not?

Comment: yup, both views are customizable (select fields, where they display). For merge fields, I'm assuming you're talking about templates? If you're creating templates, there's a `Salesforce template data mention` that lets you insert placeholders for Salesforce record fields in templates and allows updates to Salesforce, but mail merge syntax does not allow updates to Salesforce. This [document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.quip_mail_merge.htm&type=5) goes into the differences better than I can and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pT_ko3S9JA0) shows it in action.